# How to get connected web site ip adress from browser?

Tags: c#, network-programming, ip-address, detection

im trying to detect which website user connected to..

I tried to get tcp connections and i parsed them for example i tried to detect facebook. But when i logout and close facebook its still displaying 31.13.93.3 (ip of facebook)

Here is my codes..

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    static string faceIP = "31.13.93.3";
    static string _targetIP,_targetPORT,_connectedWebSiteIP,_connectedWebSitePORT = string.Empty;
    static string[] splitted = null;
    public Form1()
    {
        /* 127.0.0.1:5037:127.0.0.1:49569

         * First = 127.0.0.1
         * Second = 5037
         * Third = 127.0.01
         * Fourth = 49569
         */
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Name = "Active Tcp Connections";
        if (findFacebookIP())
        {
            MessageBox.Show("You opened or connected to facebook page!");
        }
    }
    public static bool findFacebookIP(){
        IPGlobalProperties properties = IPGlobalProperties.GetIPGlobalProperties();
        TcpConnectionInformation[] connections = properties.GetActiveTcpConnections();
        foreach (TcpConnectionInformation c in connections)
        {
            string tcpCon = string.Format("{0}:{1}", c.LocalEndPoint.ToString(), c.RemoteEndPoint.ToString());
            splitted = tcpCon.Split(':');
            _targetIP = splitted[0]; // Main Machine ip adress / local ip address (First)
            _targetPORT = splitted[1]; // Main machine port number (Second)
            _connectedWebSiteIP = splitted[2]; // (Third)
            _connectedWebSitePORT = splitted[3]; // (Fourth)
            if (_connectedWebSiteIP == faceIP)
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
    // face ip = 31.13.93.3
}
```

Also im need to run it background all time beacuse this method is working for just opening.. you can see i wrote it in Form1() constructor method.
Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Check using `TcpState`:

```
foreach (TcpConnectionInformation c in connections)
{
    //------------rest of your code
    if(c.State == TcpState.Closed)
         return false;
    //------------rest of your code
}
```

And for running in background use [`BackgroundWorker`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221403%28v=vs.95%29.aspx).

Comment: You are welcome. But if it is solved using my solution please mark my answer. :)

Comment: sorry but it wasnt your answer :) thank you for help.